# Adding anything inside a <Link>tag breaks the surrounding Blazor code

Tags: c#, blazor, blazorise

This Blazor code works as expected:
[image: Working code]

However, if I insert anything inside the `<Link>` tag, I get errors: 
[image: non-working code]

The error messages I get are false:
[image: Bad error message]

Any idea what's going on? By the way, that isn't just a Visual Studio bug; the code also doesn't build.

## Edit

For those who can't access the images, here's the code in question. Delete the "DELETE ME" to make the code work.

```
@foreach(var Child in Children)
{
    <OrderedListItem>
         <ListGroup>
            <ListGroupItem>Name: <Link To=@($"/ide/hr_child_summary/{Child["Id"]}")>DELETE ME</Link></ListGroupItem>
            <ListGroupItem>SharePoint file prefix: @Child["SharePointFilePrefix"]</ListGroupItem>
            <ListGroupItem>Dependent? @Child["Dependent"]</ListGroupItem>
        </ListGroup>
    </OrderedListItem>
}
```

### EDIT 2:

I've worked around the issue by using an `a` tag rather than a `Link`. Here's the entire component in the form that works. To reproduce the issue, change the `<a href=...>` to `<Link To=...>`. Also, in reply to comments, [`<Link>` comes from Blazorise](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/link); I didn't write it.

```
<Card> 
    <CardTitle>Relations Summary</CardTitle>
    <CardText>
        
        <ListGroup>

            <ListGroupItem>
                
                <CardSubtitle>Spouse Info</CardSubtitle>
                <ListGroup>
                    
                    <ListGroupItem>Name: <Link To=@($"/ISE/r_IDE_Summary/{IseInfo["SpouseMissionaryId"]}")>@IseInfo["SpouseName"]</Link></ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem>Employee ID: @IseInfo["SpouseEmpId"]</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem>GL Employee ID: @IseInfo["SpouseGlEmpId"]</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem>SharePoint file prefix: @IseInfo["SpouseSharePointFilePrefix"]</ListGroupItem>
                </ListGroup>
            </ListGroupItem>
            
            @if(Children?.Count > 0)
            {
                <ListGroupItem>
                    <CardSubtitle>Children</CardSubtitle>
                        <OrderedList>
                        
                        @foreach(var Child in Children)
                        {
                            <OrderedListItem>
                                <ListGroup>
                                    <ListGroupItem>Name: <a href="@($"/ide/hr_child_summary/{Child["Id"]}")">@Child["Name"]</a></ListGroupItem>
                                    <ListGroupItem>SharePoint file prefix: @Child["SharePointFilePrefix"]</ListGroupItem>
                                    <ListGroupItem>Dependent? @Child["Dependent"]</ListGroupItem>
                                </ListGroup>
                            </OrderedListItem>
                        }
                    </OrderedList>
                </ListGroupItem>
            }
        </ListGroup>
    </CardText>
</Card>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<string, string> IseInfo { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should really use code blocks instead of images. When companies (like mine) block imgur.com we can't see anything in your post besides the text.

Comment: I sympathize, and I suppose I can add a code block. The reason I used images is because I needed to show what VS was marking as errors.

Comment: I see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0irE.png

Comment: In further testing, I removed the `To` attribute altogether and moved the tag around in the code to various places. I could consistently reproduce the issue if the tag was anywhere inside the if block. But it didn't occur outside that block--and in fact, there's a very similar example outside the if block that works fine.

Comment: Does your `Link` component support `ChildContent` ? In the first image when there are no errors you don't supply and Content but in the others you do. Try removing the 'x' temporarily.

Comment: What is `<Link>` ?

Comment: `<Link>` is [part of Blazor](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/link). I didn't write it.

Comment: No, it is part of __Blazorise__, not of Blazor. And that link to already indicates this problems and gives a workaround: use `<Blazorise.Link>`. Took me 5 seconds to find that..

Comment: Except you misread that. Changing it to `<Blazorise.Link>` doesn't solve the problem, because that note is about Visual Studio, my version of VS doesn't suffer from that bug, and this issue prevents compilation in the first place, which rules out an editor bug. Plus, there are several other places where I use the `<Link>` tag without issue, including one that's in the same component that I posted in my last edit.

Comment: Right, but if you were aware of this then you should have mentioned it. And it's still not part of Blazor.

Comment: All html attributes should use quotes, see, if `To='@($"...")'` works or gives a better error.

Comment: Adding quotes has no effect, nor does omitting `To` altogether or setting it to a much simpler value (e.g., `To="x"`).

Answer (score 2):

### Totally Revised Answer

I've gone through the Blazorize source code and can't see why there's a problem, but there is!

The problem is that something in `Link` is throwing the Razor compiler so it's not compiling the C# file from the Razor file.

You can bypass the problem by coding the `RenderTreeBuilder` code directly as I've done below.

Not what you want, but...

```cs
@page "/"

@foreach (var child in _children)
{
    <ListGroup>
        @GetListItem(child)
    </ListGroup>
}

@code {
    private RenderFragment<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetListItem => (item) => (builder) =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<ListGroupItem>(0);
        builder.AddAttribute(5, "ChildContent", this.GetChildContent1(item));
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };

    private RenderFragment<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetChildContent1 => (item) => (builder) =>
    {
        builder.AddContent(0, "Name :");
        builder.OpenComponent<Link>(3);
        builder.AddAttribute(4, "To", item.Value);
        builder.AddAttribute(5, "ChildContent", this.GetChildContent(item));
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };

    private RenderFragment<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetChildContent => (item) => (builder) =>
    {
        builder.AddContent(0, item.Key);
    };

    private Dictionary<string, string> _children = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        {"Index", "/Counter" },
        {"Counter", "/Counter" },
        {"Fetch Data", "/FetchData" },
    };
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the full code.  `Link` is a standard Blazor component. `Child` is the iterator variable for the foreach loop. There's an earlier `Link` tag that works as expected.

Comment: Scott, `Link` is not a standard Blazor component: it's part of Blazorize which is a 3rd Party component library.  There is also a warning on the documentation on tooling issues and how to solve them.  Use `<Blazorise.Link>` or `<Anchor>`, not <Link>.  Is this your issue?

Comment: No, it isn't the issue, because everywhere else I use `<Link>` it works fine. I also tested whether the bug described in the documentation affects my version of Visual Studio and it doesn't. Plus, the issue I'm experiencing also prevents compilation, and an editor bug wouldn't prevent that.

Comment: ????? As I said at the top of my answer "This doesn't make sense".  Not a Blazorise fan, but if I get time later I'll install it on a solution, check it out and get back.

Comment: Neither my coworker nor I could figure this out. I can think of no explanation for the issue I described, which is what drove me to SO. I agree that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Humour me and put  `Name:` and `x` inside a span: `<span>Name :</span>`

Comment: Changing `Name:` to `<span>Name:</span>` has no effect.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information. Would you say, then, that this is a bug in Blazorise?

Comment: Not sure without a lot of investigation.  All I can say is I've written a lot of components and never encountered such an issue.  They are doing something unusual which is upsetting the Razor compiler.

Comment: It could also be that Razor reacts to the `Link` or `To` words strangely. Hard to imagine how a Component could cause this.

Comment: @HH - I've had a quick look through the source and nothing jumps out.  Anyway, it's not my component.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug that is clearly mentioned in [Blazorise documentation](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/link):

> Note: due to a [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/5527) in
> VisualStudio tooling you should write `<Link>` as `<Blazorise.Link>`
> until the issue is resolved. Or if you prefer the alternative, you can
> also use the `<Anchor>` alias.

Are you sure you tried `Blazorise.Link` because in my tests it fixes the issue:

```
@foreach (var Child in _children)
{
    <ListGroup>
        <ListGroupItem>Name: <Blazorise.Link To=@($"/ide/hr_child_summary/{Child["Id"]}")>DELETE ME</Blazorise.Link></ListGroupItem>
    </ListGroup>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The code above compiles and runs without any errors. `Anchor` alias works as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Blazor and have found that adding anything inside a `<Link>` tag breaks the surrounding code, it is likely because the `<Link>` tag is an HTML tag and not a Blazor component. Blazor components are defined using Razor syntax, which is a mix of HTML and C# code.
To use a link in Blazor, you should use the `<NavLink>` component instead. This component is specifically designed for creating links in Blazor applications and works seamlessly with the surrounding code.
For example, instead of using:html

```
<a href="/dashboard">Go to dashboard</a>
You would use:html
<NavLink href="/dashboard">Go to dashboard </NavLink>
```

This will create a link that behaves like a normal link but is also fully compatible with Blazor.

Comment: `<Link>` is part of Blazor. It isn't an HTML tag. See [the documentation](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/link).